# Beginner LINQ question: extract unique sublists of objects until list is exhausted

Tags: c#, .net, list, linq, foreach

Beginner LINQ question: how do i extract a subset of objects in the list, where object's property has common value, and then use it in a `foreach`

These are the specifics:
I have a list of these objects:

```
public class Item
{
    public string x {get; set; }
    public string y {get; set; }
}
```

In the `List<Item> itemsList` I have total of 60 `Item` objects, out of which 20 have property `x` set to "a", 10 have property `x` set to "b", and 10 have property `x` set to "c", and so on...

I want to extract a `sublist` from `itemsList` where all objects' property `x` are set to the same value and do some work on it, and keep working through it until the `itemsList` is exhausted.  something like this:

```
foreach(List<Item> subset in itemsList.??get_list_unique_by_property_x??)
{
    //do work on subset
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`GroupBy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.groupby?view=net-6.0) to group the items by the `x` property - each group will have the same value of `x`. Then iterate through the groups. For example:

```
var itemList = ...;
var groupedItems = itemList.GroupBy(item => item.x);
foreach(IEnumerable<Item> subset in groupedItems)
{
    //do work on subset
    foreach (Item item in subset)
        // do work on item
}
```